# HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache. private Date Location: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart Redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http, redirect

when I want to add product to cart, before I redirect to Cart I got this message :

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache. private Date: Sat, 27 Feb 2021 Location: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart Redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart in laravel
```

This is route for add to cart :

```
Route::post('add/{product}', 'CartController@addToCart')->name('cart.add');
```

And this is redirect in `addToCart` controller :

```
return redirect(route('cart.cart'));
```

And this is form for add to cart :

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.add',$product->id) }}" method="POST">
      @csrf
      <button type="submit" class="btn custom_button bg_color_logo1">
           Buy online                               
      </button>
</form>
```

And after show this message it will redirect to cart correctly.
Where is the problem ?

This is image :
[image: image for error]

Answer (score 0):

your `redirect` should be like this one:

```
return redirect()->route('cart.cart');
```

Comment: Still I have that message